# Swift 3 - How to add a dynamic UIViewCell on click of an UIViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have two xib files which have tableview cell designs.

On click on a cell, a web service will be called and new data will get fetched.

I want to show that data below the cell which was clicked earlier. Newly added data use a different design and it is picked up from second xib file.

Can anyone help?

Comment: please check this post of adding / configuring cells with different
[designs](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-multiple-cell-types-2df91a206429)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant provide a code example as you havent posted any code but as my knowledge I am providing a possible solution.

You can add newly downloaded data to your `UITableView datasource` and in that particular order so that new cell will appear after the user clicked on the cell.

Finally reload your `tableView`.